# How Can I convert an imageview to byte array in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

My goal is to get a picture selected by the user and populate an image view with it. Then, on clicking a button, that image will be sent to a Parse database. I know I have to convert the imageview to byte array, but Doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
here's my code:

```
 //send the imageviwew to parse database

 public void sendToParseBtn (View view){
     Bitmap bitmapImage = findViewById (R.id.imageView);
     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);

     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

     ParseFile file = new ParseFile("an.jpg",byteArray);
     ParseObject object = new ParseObject("MyParseObject");
     object.put("imageFile", file);

     object.saveInBackground();
 }
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" isn't a great description of the problem. Is there an error? If so, what? Does the code run but have an unexpected result? If so, what were you expecting and what did you see?

Comment: thx smarx, everything works except the conversion to bitmap. I think i'm not getting the image view data right. Do you know how can I select the image data from it?

Comment: You still haven't described what's wrong. How do you *know* "the conversion to bitmap" isn't working?

Comment: because the app crashes the moment I click the sendToParseBtn button

Comment: And when it crashes, what is the exception you get? (What shows up in the log?)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try converting the image view to a bitmap drawable first then get the byteArray:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
//save your stuff
```

Comment: I recommend to add  
`try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` to the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to convert `imageView` to `bytesArray`.

```
public byte[] getBytes(ImageView imageView) {
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytesData = stream.toByteArray();
        stream.close();
        return bytesData;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```